# PowerShell, error when serializing to JSON

Tags: json, powershell

I'm having the following content in a JSON file :

```
{ 
    "edit_errorcantloadgoogleaddress":  "Impossible de récupérer les propositions d\u0027adresses \"{code}\"."
}
```

parsing it and saving it back the following way :

```
$a = Get-Content -Raw -Path D:\test.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$a | ConvertTo-Json
```

I obtain the following result which *does not parse* :

```
{
    "edit_errorcantloadgoogleaddress":  "Impossible de récupérer les propositions d\u0027adresses \"{
                                            code
                                        }\"."
}
```

Does anybody have an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: the line breaks around `code` are throwing it off...

Comment: Ok, so how should I 'escape' it ? Because loading/saving the initial file with javascript (parse/stringify) does not generate any problem. Using `-Compress` fixes the problem but does not match my expectations on having a readable JSON file.

Comment: `-Compress` does seem to be the way to go. What are _your_ expectations though?

Comment: The final JSON file must be human readable. Not this easy when compressed.

Comment: I've just tried your PowerShell and the output I get is identical to the input - no additioanl line breaks.  I'm running PowerShell 4.0 on .NET 4.6 on Windows 7.  What are you running?

Comment: I'm using powerShell 3.0. I'll upgrade and try.

Comment: @user2871239 It's working under PS 4.0. It's probably a bug with 3.0. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @user2871239 mentioned, this is a version related problem, i upgraded to PS 4.0 to solve it.